# How to export power bi embedded report to power point using mvc c#

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded a power bi online report into my MVC C# application and its rendering properly. Further i am trying to export it into power point, but didn't got a way to do it. It is available in Power Bi Online version. I have searched over the forums and on google but didn't got any solution for this. Is there any possibility to do it using any tools/third party controls.

Answer (score 1):

The 'export to powerpoint' API is not yet available to REST APIs.
There is no known ETA for this, however, product team has informed it is aware of the ask and are working on enabling this.

Comment: Thanks RBreuer, have you tried "devscope " http://www.devscope.net/products/PowerBITilesPro/default.aspx for this?